# Download folder with all content recursively, Sharpbox

Tags: c#, dropbox-api, sharpbox

So I set up a little app that I would like to use to download A folder from my public Dropbox folder and all the content within that to a vm.

If I try:

```
var publicFolder = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/Public");
string targetFile = @"C:\Users\Michael\";
dropBoxStorage.DownloadFile(publicFolder,@"WS",targetFile);
```

WS if the Folder with all the content that I would like to download.

However when i run the code I get: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharpBox does not support downloading folders.
I took the time and wrote a function which should download the folder recursively. (haven't tested it though).

```
string remoteDirName = @"/Public/WS";
string targetDir = @"C:\Users\Michael\";
var remoteDir = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder(remoteDirName);

public static DownloadFolder(CloudStorage dropBoxStorage,ICloudDirectoryEntry remoteDir, string targetDir)
{

    foreach (ICloudFileSystemEntry fsentry in remoteDir)
    {
        if (fsentry is ICloudDirectoryEntry)
        {
            DownloadFolder(dropBoxStorage, fsentry, Path.Combine(targetDir, fsentry.Name));
        }
        else
        {
            dropBoxStorage.DownloadFile(remoteDir,fsentry.Name,Path.Combine(targetDir, fsentry.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of SharpBox does this relate too?

Comment: It also gives an error on the DownloadFolder line in the if statement.

Comment: As i said, it hasn't been tested. It could still need some work, it's just the general idea. In the case you specified you might have top pass to the function `DownloadFolder(dropBoxStorage, fsentry as ICloudDirectoryEntry, Path.Combine(targetDir, fsentry.Name));` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help non the less

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with below code also..

```
var PublicFolder = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/Public");
 if (PublicFolder != null && PublicFolder.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
 DownloadFolder(dropBoxStorage, PublicFolder as ICloudDirectoryEntry, targetPath);
}



public static void DownloadFolder(CloudStorage dropBoxStorage, ICloudDirectoryEntry remoteDir, string targetDir)
    {
        foreach (var fof in remoteDir.ToList())
        {

            if (fof is ICloudDirectoryEntry)
            {
                DirectoryInfo newDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(targetDir, fof.Name));
                if (!newDir.Exists)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(targetDir, fof.Name));
                }

                DownloadFolder(dropBoxStorage, fof as ICloudDirectoryEntry, Path.Combine(targetDir, fof.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                dropBoxStorage.DownloadFile(remoteDir, fof.Name, Path.Combine(targetDir));
            }

        }
    }
```